# Как вызвать классы Yii2 в отдельном файле?

Tags: php, yii2, socket.io

Суть задачи: у меня в корне проекта лежит файл server.php. Он используется для работы сокета.

У меня в нем описаны функции для сокетов и я хочу, что бы когда срабатывается какая то функция, я мог что то делать в базе проекта.

Например, когда срабатывает функция, что пришло новое сообщение, я хочу что бы это новое сообщение так же записалось в базу.

Код server.php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$io = new \PHPSocketIO\SocketIO(2020);
$io->on('connection', function($socket){
$socket->addedUser = false;
// when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes
$socket->on('new message', function ($message, $user_to, $user_from, 
$data, $img)use($socket){
    // we tell the client to execute 'new message'
    $sms=new \frontend\models\Messages();
    $sms->from_user=$user_from;
    $sms->to_user=$user_to;
    $sms->text=$message;
    $sms->data=$data;
    $sms->status=0;
    return $sms->save() ? $sms : null;
    }


    $socket->broadcast->emit('new message', array(
        'message'=> $message,
        'user_to'=> $user_to,
        'user_from'=>$user_from,
        'data'=>$data,
        'img'=>$img
    ));
});

});

\Workerman\Worker::runAll();
```

Но этот код не срабатывает, говорит что не может найти класс Message. Как к нему можно обратится с этого файла?

Answer (score 1):

Первое, возможно new \frontend\models\Message(),а не  Message**s**().

Второе, проверьте правильность namspace зайдите в класс Message и проверьте его неймспейс.

Третье больше совет. Используйте use

```
use \frontend\models\Messages
```

Comment: в классе namespace задан так - namespace frontend\models; в server.php пробовал и так - use \frontend\models\Messages; и так - use frontend\models\Messages; - результат один и тот же - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'frontend\models\Messages' not found